# Should we always dump json as string to a server?

Tags: python, json, webserver

Supposed I am writing a proxy server that sits between my app server and my app.

```
import json, requests
requests.post("http://localhost:8080", data=json.dumps({"password": "password"}))
requests.post("http://localhost:8080", data={"password": "password"})
```

According to my current implementation, I read in the stream of data and I print out the content-type and the body.

```
[]
{"password": "password"}
['application/x-www-form-urlencoded']
password=password
```

In practice, what should a webserver do? We look at the content-type and we see `application/json`, we will definitely try to encode it back to a JSON data structure. So should we always expect users to dump to string and send the server or not?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking which of the two `POST` versions you should use? If you're using a defined protocol (rather than making up your own) this will be decided for you.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am asking whether popular server expects to see a string version ``{"key": "value"}`` or not. When I say string I mean encoding your dict into a string representation. In the second request, requests library automatically thinks this is a form submission (okay fine, let's ignore that part and assumt we are sending ``application/json``) I can still decode key=value&key2=value into a dictionary on the server side. Or should we fast fail because json should expect to see ``{key:value}``.

Comment: If your server expects JSON, you should send JSON. If it expects URL encoded keys and values, you should send that instead. There's no one answer, you just need the client to send what the server expects.